# jQuery mobile slide transition animation in Safari iOS7 when swiping back is jumpy

Tags: jquery, mobile, ios7, safari, transition

I have a simple link like

```
<a href="about/staff.php" data-transition="slide">Staff</a>
```

The slide transition animates nicely when you tap the link and animates out nicely when you tap the back button.

The problem arises when a user in safari (iOS7) uses the "swipe to go back" gesture on the edge of the screen. The page goes back but the animation occurs again after the page loads which looks very poor.

You can see the problem on the documentation example here
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/transitions/ (tap the page button next to slide, then swipe to go back)

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I could not replicate what you are describing in Safari iOS7. Clicking the back button or the "Take me back" link does not make the animation occur again.

Comment: @JSuar Right, if you press the back button it works as expected. Its when you use the "swipe to go back" native to Safari iOS7 that I see the double animation...

Answer (score 1):

IOS7 safari browser comes with swipe gestures itself as you mentioned. This page [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/transitions/page-transitions-page.html) also uses slide transitions native to safari browser. when the user swipes back from current page, it doesn't just change stuff on [transitions page](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/transitions/) but also changes the URL as well so the browser actually takes you to previous page. The page transitions might be conflicting with browser's transitions and in result you get double animation of page and browser.

Comment: Yes, is there a way around the conflict?